# Change postgres user password in hot standby read only mode

Tags: postgresql, replication, database-replication

I want to change the password of the `postgres` user on my PostgreSQL Slave Server which is in read-only mode because of an active replication. `SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();` returns true and because of this I can't change the password - so far so good.

How can I temporarily pause the replication (and read-only mode) to set a new password for the `postgres` user? `SELECT pg_xlog_replay_pause();` and  didn't work.

Or should I reset the postgres password on the master server and then I have identically passwords on the master & slave?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You need to change the password on the master

Comment: Changing the DB user password on master will replicate on slave as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hot-standby.html

> When the hot_standby parameter is set to true on a standby server, it
>   will begin accepting connections once the recovery has brought the
>   system to a consistent state. All such connections are strictly
>   read-only; not even temporary tables may be written.

and so forth the list of what you can do on the slave. You can NOT `ALTER USER` on slave - do it on master and it will be replicated to slave. What you can try to do to have different passwords though is:

1. change password on master - it will replicate to slave so you have same passwords
2. `pg_xlog_replay_pause` on slave to stop replaying form master
3. change password back on master

this way you will have different passwords for a while (until you resume replay)